# Prove that $n$ is also a power of $2$.

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

An arithmetic progression consists of integers. The sum of the first $n$ terms of this progression is a power of two.

Prove that $n$ is also a power of two.

Source :http://www.math.ucla.edu/~radko/circles/lib/data/Handout-967-1026.pdf

Comment: Hint:  if you know $a_1$ and $a_n$, what is the sum of the first $n$ terms?

Comment: @Amar30657 it would be better for you if you could show your approach !

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Given first term $a$ and common difference $d$, sum of first $n$ terms, $S_n$ is given by
$$S_n=\frac{n}{2}\left(2a+(n-1)d\right)$$
Let $S_n=2^k$ where $k\in\mathbb Z$. We must have $k\ge 0$ as the arithmetic progression consists of integers.
$$2^k=\frac{n}{2}\left(2a+(n-1)d\right)$$
$$2^{k+1}=n\left(2a+(n-1)d\right)\in\mathbb Z^+$$

As the prime factorization of an integer is unique, $n$ must be of the form $2^r$, where $r\ge0$. Thus, $n$ must be a power of $2$.

Answer (score 3):

The sum of an arithmetic progression equals the number of terms times an integer or a half-integer. If twice the sum is a power of two, then both factors are a power of two.

Answer (score 3):

See that the sum of first $n$ terms is $s = \frac{n * (a_{1} + a_{n})}{2} = 2^{k}(say)$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ ,now both $a_{1},a_{n}$ are integers means that $n$ must be a power of $2$.

Comment: In fact we have proved the stronger statement that if $a_i$ are the terms of _any_ arithmetic progression, and if (for a particular $n$) $a_1+a_n$ happens to be an integer, then if the sum $s=a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n$ is a power of two, then $n$ is a power of two.

Comment: Yes , that is good and stronger condition .

Answer (score 3):

$$S_n=\frac{n}{2}\left(a + a_n\right) = 2^k$$
$$\log_2 (S_n)=\log_2(n) + \log_2(a+a_n) = {k+1}$$
Since $k+1$ is an integer, $\log_2(n)$ must be an integer as well. Hence, $n$ is a power of $2$.